# click event not working when clicking on element which is oustide the parent container

Tags: vue.js

```
<div :style="`width: ${width - 40}px;`"
          @click="
            () => {
              showWarning = !showWarning;
            }
          "
        >
```

I have made the element larger then than the container element. when I click on the element outside the parent container the eventlistner is not triggered. but onclick works when i click on the part of the element that in inside the parent
[image]

Comment: can you share your full component or working example on codesandbox or stackblitz please. Also do you have any errors in console etc ?

Comment: @thezohaan please don't ask people to post their code on external sites.   SO questions should be self-contained; the code snippet tool can be used for working examples.

Comment: @SalilRajkarnikar how is the element larger than its container?  Are there overflow rules on the parent perhaps?   Please include a [mcve] demonstrating what you're doing; we cant' really tell what's going on with an element you haven't included in the question.

Comment: @thezohaan Yes, it is possible to use Vue in snippets.  (Also,  this specific question doesn't appear to require vue to demonstrate the problem; it's just click events on DOM elements)

Comment: container is the eleent od table <td>. and i game my element width that is the width of enture table as shown above. so its larger than the parent. @
Daniel Beck

Comment: OK, that's not how tables work; changing the width of a table cell or its contents to match the width of the full table will (depending on your layout methods) just make the table bigger to make room for the other cells in the row, or lose the extra space to overflow. You'll need to show an example of the table and its contents and any related CSS for us to be able to give more detailed advice.  (Alternatively, the dev tools DOM inspector can show you the actual size and placement of the resulting elements, so you can more easily see what's happening in your own code.)

Comment: @DanielBeck i have added the image for layout in the question. u see the error that needs to be display is larder rhan the td. so when i click outside the td thr dropdown(onclick) dosent work

Comment: I can’t tell from that image what is the boundaries of the td, or where you’re clicking and expecting a drop-down to trigger, or which of the three drop-downs in the image you expect to fire. I’m giving up on this one, but if you want help from someone else your best bet, again, is to put together a [mcve] demonstrating the problem; that is often much clearer than trying to describe it